# WP_Query('orderby=post_date') not working with wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

`WP_Query('orderby=post_date')` is not working with wordpress.

how do I sort my posts in descending order?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
WP_Query('orderby=date&order=DESC')
```

Comment: have a test i don't know , if it's not what you're looking for then have a look at $wpdb and run you're own query

Comment: Here's a list of columns to order by w/ descriptions: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

Comment: where to write $args variable then

Comment: @AllenGingrich please explain why ?

Comment: What about ASC?

Answer (score 13):

The following 3 parameters will give you the posts in Ascending order from the date it was published *(i.e The older posts will be shown first)*

**'post_status' => 'publish', 'orderby' => 'publish_date', 'order' => 'ASC'**

When you change the *order* to *DESC* you will get the posts in Descending order from the date it was published *(i.e The latest posts will be shown first)*

**'post_status' => 'publish', 'orderby' => 'publish_date', 'order' => 'DESC'**

```
<?php
$postsPerPage = 10;
$page = 1;
?>
<?php
$query = new WP_Query(array(
    'cat' => 4,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby' => 'publish_date',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'paged' => $page,
    'posts_per_page' => $postsPerPage));
?>
```

Answer (score 8):

To order by the modification date you have use `orderby=modified`.

```
WP_Query( 'orderby=modified&order=DESC' )
```

See [the documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) for more possible values.

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $args = array(
    "post_type" => "post",
      "post_status" => "publish",
      "paged" => $paged,
      "orderby" => "date",
      "order" => 'ASC'
       );
     WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: this is the method i am looking for

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `PostTypesOrder plugin` it might globally modify your query, in order to avoid this behaviour to particular post type

```
add_filter('pto/posts_orderby/ignore', 'theme_pto_posts_orderby', 10, 3);

function theme_pto_posts_orderby($ignore, $orderBy, $query)
{
       if( (! is_array($query->query_vars['post_type']) && $query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'post') ||
       (is_array($query->query_vars)   &&  in_array('post', $query->query_vars)))
               $ignore = TRUE;
       return $ignore;
}
```

Comment: Also you can use:
`'ignore_custom_sort' => true` in the query

Answer (score 1):

Just one more note, I pulled my hair out because all the time I was getting the same items in the list, than I realized I needed to add:

```
'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
```

I hope someone else will notice this before I did.

Comment: In which file can I add this changes?

Comment: You add it in the same file as your query, within the args.

Comment: This worked for me.